# MeteorJS force logout of client when user record deleted

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have seen the recommended method of

```
Meteor.users.update({}, {$set: { "services.resume.loginTokens" : [] }});
```

to logout a user, but that only works when the page is refreshed.

I'm looking for a way that when I remove the user from the database, it logs out the user.  I need the following code to force a logout on the client IF the client was logged in for that user.  I cannot wait for the user to refresh the page.

```
Meteor.users.remove({_id: this.userId})
```

EDIT:

I have verified that this behavior in on my angular pages and not when I'm on a Meteor template.  When I am on a Meteor template, it seems to work, but when I move to an angular route it stops behaving as required.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: what about using `observe()`? http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack any idea if `observe()` or `observeChanges()` is a push notification?  It looks like it's pull :(.  This compacted by the fact that I would have to have it on the client means it can be circumvented.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by push/pull. `observe()` and its cousin take a callback that they call once the data the cursor is pointing to changes. And no, it doesn't have to be on the client. The documentation says it can be in the server or client.

Comment: Oh hey. I made a test project, created the account, and then in a shell ran `meteor shell` then `Meteor.users.remove({_id: 'myIDhere'})` and it logged me out automatically. Looks like this is built-in functionality.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack While observe can be on the server or the client, the `Meteor.logout()` functionality has to be on the client.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack I haven't tried with meteor shell yet.  When I did it using `meteor mongo` `db.users.remove({})` while the username disappeared, any of the pub/sub requests still worked (IE: the data still appeared on the page)

Comment: Ahh, Angular. Sorry, can't help you then :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using something reactive that is tied in to checking who the current user is.

If your using iron router, there is examples of using login mappers to redirect users to login pages when the user is unauthorized.

Something akin to

```
if(!Meteor.user()) { window.location = '/login'; };
```

If you delete the user from the users table, that will invalidate and redirect you.

Obviously you would need to have conditions that protect certain areas from invalidating this - but the general idea is in just using reactive variables.

Comment: this only works when the user navigates away from the page they are on, causing the routs to be hit again.  This does not auto redirect for the page the user is currently on.